# Proof for Vector Spaces $V = U + W$ with $U \cap W = {\mathbf{0}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces

I am going through question in my text book regarding proof. I have done that but I think I am making mistake of proving that $u_1=u_2$ and $w_1=w_2$ by using this same statement that I have to prove. Am I wrong or I have done following proof correctly. Kindly help

> **Question:**
> If $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of vector space $V$ such that $V = U + W$ and $U \cap W = {\mathbf{0}}$, then prove that every vector in $V$ has a unique representation of the form $\mathbf{u} + \mathbf{w}$, where $\mathbf{u} \in U$ and $\mathbf{w} \in W$.( $V$ is called the *direct sum of* $U$ *and* $W$, and is written $V = U \oplus W$. )

**Proof:**

Existence: For any $\mathbf{v} \in V$, since $V = U + W$, $\exists \mathbf{u} \in U, \mathbf{w} \in W$ such that $\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{u} + \mathbf{w}$.

Uniqueness: Suppose $\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{u}_1 + \mathbf{w}_1 = \mathbf{u}_2 + \mathbf{w}_2$, where $\mathbf{u}_1, \mathbf{u}_2 \in U$ and $\mathbf{w}_1, \mathbf{w}_2 \in W$.

Then, $\mathbf{u}_1 - \mathbf{u}_2 = \mathbf{w}_2 - \mathbf{w}_1$. Since $U$ and $W$ are subspaces, $\mathbf{u}_1 - \mathbf{u}_2 \in U$ and $\mathbf{w}_2 - \mathbf{w}_1 \in W$. Therefore, this vector is in $U \cap W$.

Given $U \cap W = {\mathbf{0}}$, $\mathbf{u}_1 - \mathbf{u}_2 = \mathbf{w}_2 - \mathbf{w}_1 = \mathbf{0}$. Thus, $\mathbf{u}_1 = \mathbf{u}_2$ and $\mathbf{w}_1 = \mathbf{w}_2$.

Comment: Your proof is completely correct.

Comment: @StephaneJaouen To be fair, $U\cap W=0$ is a pretty common notation in abstract algebra. I believe when you learn a basic course like linear algebra it is better to use the more formal $\{0\}$ notation though.

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen It's not uncommon use $0$ to denote the subspace $\{0\}$. I don't know if the OP is aware of this but if the textbook use that notation, your correction without these context could confuse the OP. (Mark beat me to comment on this)

Comment: @StéphaneJaouen: standard mathematical notation is heavily overloaded. It is absolutely standard to use $0$ for the trivial vector space. In your notation for a vector space, do you use different symbols for vector addition and scalar addition (and likewise for the two multiplications)?  If you are working with two different vector spaces, do you use notation that distinguishes the constants and operations on those spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is completely correct. There is nothing to add a priori, but nevertheless I regret the absence of *drawings* and *examples* because of the close link between linear algebra and elementary geometry.
[image]
It is understandable that in a textbook, the teacher avoids drawings in order to focus his readers on reasoning independently of the drawing, which are only supports that are not absolutely necessary. On the other hand, it is strongly recommended that the student of the same book multiply the drawings and look for examples in his knowledge. Here, it's simple: we can take for example the vector space over $\mathbb R$ $$V:=(\mathbb R^2,+,.)$$  $$U:=\mathbb R (1,0)$$ $$W:=\mathbb R (0,1)$$
What you have shown then allows you to assert that any element $(x,y)$ of $\mathbb R^2$ has a unique representation of the form $u+w$, with $u\in U$ and $w\in W$, which you will no doubt recognize:$$\text{Denoting } \vec i=(1,0) , \vec j=(0,1), \forall \vec v\in V, \exists !(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2: \vec v=x\vec i+ y \vec j$$